# Cognito Forms Key for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, cognito-forms

I'm trying to add the form to a WordPress post and it's asking me for the key. My account is already validated. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the issue, please make sure you log out of Cognito Forms in any other browser pages you have open. Then, log into Cognito Forms only though the WordPress app.

Once you have logged in through the WordPress app, the necessary keys will auto-generate for your account and you should then be able to embed a form.

I am a developer for Cognito Forms.

Comment: I am not getting it right I followed your instructions and logged in via Cognito's Wordpress app only and it did not auto-generate the necessary keys. I would like to embed forms on my site Please tell me what I can do.